# VIM change path to where it was invoked

Tags: vim, grep

I really like my vim to change its working dir to the file I'm currently working on. For this I use in my vimrc:

`autocmd BufEnter * if bufname("") !~ "^\[A-Za-z0-9\]*://" | lcd %:p:h | endif`

What I also like is using `gF`(*) in vim to open files under the cursor in a new buffer.

This combination, however, induces a problem in my preferred workflow:

1. Let's say I want to find all occurrences of "foo" in a project, so with my shell I `cd` to the folder `path/to/project/src` and execute: `grep -Ern 'foo' * | vim -`.
   For the sake of the argument the output, which is opened in vim is:

   `a/file1.c:42: foo
   b/file2.c:13: foo`
2. Now I want to inspect the hit in `file1` so I use `gF` to jump into it. This action changes the working directory to `path/to/project/src/a`
3. When I go back to the tab with the output of `grep` the working directory stays at `path/to/project/src/a` because `%:p:h` apparently cannot resolve a path for something read from stdin.
4. Problem: I now cannot jump into `file2` via `gF` since the relative path is now wrong.

It would be nice to make vim automatically change its working directory to the location where it was invoked when switching to a buffer. For this example, this means when switching to the `grep` buffer I expect my working directory to be `path/to/project/src`.

I would be grateful for any ideas on how to achieve this.

(*) Full disclosure: I use [spf-13 vim](https://github.com/spf13/spf13-vim) but the basic problem should apply to vim in general.

Comment: You can execute `grep -Ern 'foo' $PWD/* | vim -`. Grep prints full path then and vim jumps to the file regardless the current directory.

Comment: Thanks for the workaround! A real solution through vim would however still be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Instead of your `:autocmd`, you can simply use `:set autochdir` in your `~/.vimrc`. Vim has this feature built-in since many versions.
- Instead of using `grep` externally, try the built-in `:grep` (or `:vimgrep`) commands. The results will populate the *quickfix list*; the nice thing about that is that paths will automatically be adapted to changes in the working directory.

Comment: `:grep` and then using the quickfix list is actually a pretty decent solution. Didn't know about that one. Thx.

Comment: I just want to manually change directory. This helped me realize I could do so using `:chdir`. Thanks!